# How can I use R to remove a file extension that is not alphanumeric extension

Tags: r

This is an example of the file name

```
MOD09A1.A2000049.h19v11.005.2006268194400.hdf.sur_refl_day_of_year
```

Initially it was

```
MOD09A1.A2000049.h19v11.005.2006268194400.hdf.sur_refl_day_of_year.tif
```

I used the function `file_path_sans_ext` to remove ".tiff" but I still want to remove ".sur_refl_day_of_year".
I just need the file name `MOD09A1.A2000049.h19v11.005.2006268194400.hdf` only.

Comment: Just call `file_path_sans_ext` twice — no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thought so too and tried that but it didn't work. Did some digging and was told that only purely alphanumeric extensions are recognized...like ".tiff".

Comment: oh, you're right. What an utterly badly done function.

Comment: like @KonradRudolph mentions, you can use a generic function to remove the part after the last `.` such as `f <- function(x) gsub('\\.\\w+$', '', x)` and just use it twice `f(f(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sub("(\\.hdf).*", "\\1", myfilename)
```

Comment: The first period is a wildcard rather than matching a period so you might want to double escape it or put it in a character-class "box".

Answer (score 1):

`fs::path_ext_remove` is what you are after.

[Docs](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/path_file.html)